# Flipping object plugin not working properly in webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the below web page , the top 4 objects flip fine and smoothly , while the 2 in the 2nd row don't they sometimes even flip when mouse hovered over the empty area between the 2 boxes in the 2nd row, what could have possibly gone wrong.

[click](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/141359479/cevents.html)

Comment: Everything seems fine? Can you please be more detailed on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this css property with `!important`:

```
#nav-list-example li div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0 !important; //<-----this one with !important
}
```

`left: 135px;` this caused the issue. fix it by as above suggested.

Comment: @rahul888 have you tried this? your issue is fixed or not plz respond.

Comment: i tried but what it does that it does not center, they second row objects just align below the 1st and 2nd box of first row..!!!